# Search result order in sharepoint 2007

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

we have portal in sharepoint 2007. We have one document library with 2 custom columns named as Account,Customer name.
 
We want to add some ordering to show sharepoint default search result.
Orderig means if user enters word "Monitor" in simple search box, then result should appear in below way, 
First all those document should appear in result who have word "Monitor" in its custom column Account, 
then all documents should appear who have word "Monitor" in its custom column Customer name and finally all documents who have word "Monitor" in its document content.

Is there any way by which I can implement this search result ordering in sharepoint?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this cannot be done in Out-of-the box SharePoint Search beyond what is possible with [Best Bets and Keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/add-edit-and-delete-keyword-best-bets-HA001160577.aspx), which probably isn't what you are looking for.

A second option would be for you to write your own [SharePoint search page / web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455094%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which would let you query the search index and then process the results as you see fit.

Another option would be to use the FAST Search engine which has a [programmable pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795801.aspx) that might let you write your own components to get the desired result.  This is definitely not for the technically timid, however.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help.We are unable to decide this is possible or not.
Now we are thinking of using keyword or fulltextquery to get this done